# CMD - delete all files lower than size

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filesystems

I have about 500 folders in a network path each containing 2 to 3 files higher than 500mb. They also contain several other files and subdirectories.

I only need to keep bigger files in the root of each directory, all the rest may be deleted.

Is there any way to do this by batch/cmd command?
Or are there nifty gui tools available that you might recommend?

Comment: `forfiles /?` should help u out

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well its all good now and fixed.
As I was using Synology I didn't pay attention to the filter mechanism in the File Explorer (an amazing and easy to use feature). So I used that instead, Thanks though for the replies, I might use the forfiles in another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the internal feature of Synology (Filter in the File Explorer)